# Stream Mixxx headphone output via IceCast

Tags: headphones, streaming, icecast

Just like the title.

Is it possible to configure Mixxx and Icecast in such a way that the headphone output is streamed? (Instead of the master output) How?

My laptop has only one sound card. I thought, maybe it's possible to connect my phone (via icecast?) to the headphone output. That way, I can use my phone's output (by listening to the Icecast stream) to pre-listen and use the laptop audio out as master.

I don't think doing the opposite (master over icecast on the phone, pre-listen via the laptop audio out) would be such a great idea, as streaming is inherently unreliable and I don't want to put the master over an unreliable connection. And then there's the latency. Pre-listening with all these flaws seems to be less of a problem to me (it just doesn't work in the worst case, and then the master is unaffected).

Another solution to do something like this would also be accepted. As long as it makes it possible to reliably do pre-listening with an extra audio output.

I've quickly looked at possibly using the mic as output but that seems far too much trouble:

- [Using microphone input port as headphone output](https://askubuntu.com/questions/27804/using-microphone-input-port-as-headphone-output)
- [How do I get my laptop's Line In inlet to output sound?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/43413/how-do-i-get-my-laptops-line-in-inlet-to-output-sound)

But if someone knows, it'd be the best solution. I have a ThinkPad T60.

Answer (score 2):

I've figured out how to set up IceCast2 for the master and stream from there, but the latency is *far* too much (roughly 7s what I've measured). So this isn't going to work. If someone knows a way to do something like this with much lower latency (at the very least <1s, but something like 100ms is more reasonable), that would be a solution.